# how to open URL Field link in new window SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, url

I am using **UrlField** for link button,I want to open URL in new window.

```
<SharePointWebControls:UrlField ID="UrlField2" FieldName="Link Button" runat="server"/>
```

I have tried **target="_blank"** but it does not work.

So, is there a way to open the UrlField in a new tab ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open in new tab is only supported in Publishing URL field. You are using the basic URL field. You need to use `PublishingWebControls:RichLinkField`. This will give you the "open in new window" option.

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Since the control has a CssClass Property, you could manipulate the **target** attribute using JQuery. For example (not tested):

```
<SharePointWebControls:UrlField ID="UrlField2" FieldName="Link Button" runat="server" CssClass="item-link" />
```

And on the JQuery side:

```
$(function() {
    $(".item-link").attr('target', '_blank');
});
```